# when / then / otherwise with values from numpy array

Tags: python-polars

Say I have

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({'group': [1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4]})
```

I have a numpy array of values, which I'd like to replace `'group'` 3 with

```py
values = np.array([9, 8, 7])
```

Here's what I've tried:

```py
(
    df
    .with_column(
        pl.when(pl.col('group')==3)
        .then(values)
        .otherwise(pl.col('group')
    ).alias('group')
)
```

```py
In [4]: df.with_column(pl.when(pl.col('group')==3).then(values).otherwise(pl.col('group')).alias('group'))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [4], line 1
----> 1 df.with_column(pl.when(pl.col('group')==3).then(values).otherwise(pl.col('group')).alias('group'))

File ~/tmp/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/polars/internals/whenthen.py:132, in When.then(self, expr)
    111 def then(
    112     self,
    113     expr: (
   (...)
    121     ),
    122 ) -> WhenThen:
    123     """
    124     Values to return in case of the predicate being `True`.
    125
   (...)
    130
    131     """
--> 132     expr = pli.expr_to_lit_or_expr(expr)
    133     pywhenthen = self._pywhen.then(expr._pyexpr)
    134     return WhenThen(pywhenthen)

File ~/tmp/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/polars/internals/expr/expr.py:118, in expr_to_lit_or_expr(expr, str_to_lit)
    116     return expr.otherwise(None)
    117 else:
--> 118     raise ValueError(
    119         f"did not expect value {expr} of type {type(expr)}, maybe disambiguate with"
    120         " pl.lit or pl.col"
    121     )

ValueError: did not expect value [9 8 7] of type <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, maybe disambiguate with pl.lit or pl.col
```

How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to consider.

- One is that you always should convert your numpy arrays to polars `Series` as we will use the arrow memory specification underneath and not numpys.
- Second is that `when -> then -> otherwise` operates on columns that are of equal length. We nudge the API in such a direction that you define a logical statement based of columns in your `DataFrame` and therefore you should not know the indices (nor the lenght of a group) that you want to replace. This allows for much optimizations because if you do not define indices to replace we can push down a filter before that expression.

Anyway, your specific situation does know the length of the group, so we must use something different. We can first compute the indices where the conditional holds and then modify based on those indices.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "group": [1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4]
})

values = np.array([9, 8, 7])

# compute indices of the predicate
idx = df.select(
    pl.arg_where(pl.col("group") == 3)
).to_series()

# mutate on those locations
df.with_column(
    df["group"].set_at_idx(idx, pl.Series(values))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's all I could come up with

```py
df.with_column(
    pl.col("group")
    .cumcount()
    .over(pl.col("group"))
    .alias("idx")
).apply(
    lambda x: values[x[1]] if x[0] == 3 else x[0]
).select(
    pl.col("apply").alias("group")
)
```

Surely there's a simpler way?

```py
In [28]: df.with_column(pl.col('group').cumcount().over(pl.col('group')).alias('idx')).apply(lambda x:
    ...:  values[x[1]] if x[0] == 3 else x[0]).select(pl.col('apply').alias('group'))
Out[28]:
shape: (8, 1)
┌───────┐
│ group │
│ ---   │
│ i64   │
╞═══════╡
│ 1     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 9     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 8     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 7     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4     │
└───────┘
```